# Regular Expression for date format validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What is the regular expression for date format (**mm-dd-yyyy**) and validating them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is

```
((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-(([0-2]\d)|([3][01]))-(\d{4})
```

Explanation:

1. Since `mm` can be any thing from `01` to `12` so to suffice `01-09`, regular expression would be `0[1-9]` or as `mm` can also be `10-12` so `1[0-2]`.

   **Hence the regular expression to match `mm` would be `(0\d)|(1[0-2])`**
2. As `dd` can be any thing from `01` to `31` so to suffice `01-29` regular expression would be `[0-2]\d` or it can also be `30-31` so `[3][01]`.

   **Hence the regular expression to match `dd` would be `(([0-2]\d)|([3][01]))`**
3. As `yyyy` can be any number of 4 digits i.e. 2010, 1999, 2050 etc (as long as you are not considering any specificrange) so the regular expression would simply be 4 digits i.e. `\d{4}`.

   **Hence the regular expression to match `yyyy` would be `(\d{4})`**

So after combining these, the complete regular expression for the date would be:

```
((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-(([0-2]\d)|([3][01]))-(\d{4})
```

Comment: Thank You friends this is very use full for me

Comment: Your "Here it is" regular expression at the top does not match your expression at the bottom : your day should be `[0-2]\d`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl actually I edited the question later and forgot to update that. Updated now. Thanks